# How to skip "Hit return to start merge resolution tool" and open mergetool automatically

Tags: git, git-config, mergetool

Git asking to hit return button to open the mergetool for each conflict file one by one:

```
> git mergetool 
Normal merge conflict for '...':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff):
```

How can I avoid the hitting return step for my project and just open the configured merge tool automatically?

Comment: Note: the next Git release (2.0.x, Q3 2014) won't display that message anymore if mergetool is defined. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716878/6309).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-y` flag.  From the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html):

> **`-y`**
>   **`--no-prompt`**
>   Don’t prompt before each invocation of the merge resolution program.

Answer (score 12):

To permanently skip the prompt, run:

```
git config --global mergetool.prompt false
```

To skip it for a single run of `git mergetool`, pass `-y` or `--no-prompt`:

```
git mergetool -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: GIt 2.0.x (Q3 2014) won't display that message if you have explicitely defined your `merge.tool`.
No need for a `-y` anymore.

See [commit 4ecc63d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ecc63d7f982aa65038048bcdaf49e99b428b028) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec):

#### `mergetool`: run prompt only if guessed tool

> It's annoying to see the prompt:

```
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (foo):
```

> Every time the user does '`git mergetool`' even if the user already configured '`foo`' as the wanted tool.
>
> Display this prompt only when the user hasn't explicitly configured a tool.

See [`git-mergetool--lib.sh#L323-L339`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4ecc63d7f982aa65038048bcdaf49e99b428b028/git-mergetool--lib.sh#L323-L339) for the "explicitly defined" part: `git config merge.tool`

---

This is clarified by [commit c15bb0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c15bb0cad73e4dad52a6d4869a254baf3a689b6a):

```
-y::
--no-prompt::
```

> Don't prompt before each invocation of the merge resolution program.
>
> **This is the default** if the merge resolution program is explicitly specified with the `--tool` option or with the `merge.tool` configuration variable.

```
--prompt::
```

> Prompt before each invocation of the merge resolution program to give the user a chance to skip the path.

Comment: Merged in https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ea60c15cc98ab586aea77c256934acd438c7f95

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your `.gitconfig` file. Usually, it is at `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
```

The above-suggested methods eventually do that. Adding this answer since it helps to know where the command makes the change.